# Docker run command ignoring part of Dockerfile CMD when ENTRYPOINT present

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I run my docker container, it appears to only be honouring the first element of the CMD array (python executable) and ignoring the trailing parameters.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
CMD ["/virtualenv/bin/python", "/mycode/myscript.py", "--param1"]
```

Run command:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --volume $(pwd)/..:/mycode --volume mycontainer-virtualenv:/virtualenv mycontainer
```

Output:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Same happens if I run `--detach` instead of `-it`.

Same also happens if I run with the CMD as an overriding docker run parameter:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --volume $(pwd)/..:/mycode --volume mycontainer-virtualenv:/virtualenv mycontainer /virtualenv/bin/python /mycode/myscript.py --param1
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If I run the container with bash and run the CMD from the bash prompt, it works fine:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --volume $(pwd)/..:/mycode --volume mycontainer-virtualenv:/virtualenv mycontainer bash
root@d6a990e81c22:/# /virtualenv/bin/python /mycode/myscript.py --param1
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
CMD ["/virtualenv/bin/python /mycode/myscript.py --param1"]
```

instead of

```
CMD ["/virtualenv/bin/python", "/mycode/myscript.py", "--param1"]
```

When `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` are both present in Dockerfile, CMD works as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT. So you basically doing

```
bash -c "/virtualenv/bin/python" "/mycode/myscript.py" "--param1"
```

when you want

```
bash -c "/virtualenv/bin/python /mycode/myscript.py --param1"
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact